# how to add a photo to scratch background?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, scratch

how to add a photo to scratch background on raspberry Pi 3 model B.
I just want my background to be different as usual because I have already used all of the other backgrounds and I find them boring!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an image background to scratch on the Raspberry Pi 3, do the following.

- Select the stage tab.[image]
- Click the backgrounds tab, and click import.[image]
- You should see a file browser show up.  Click on the image you would like to use for your background.  I'm using a picture located in the home folder of my Pi `~/Pictures/Wallpapers`.

[image]

- And voila!  You should be able to see your new background now instead of the default ones.
  [image]

Comment if you need anymore help on the subject.  I'll do it gladly.

Comment: I have done that but my Pi doesn't let me even see any pictures to add

Comment: @user128854 Have you downloaded any pictures?

Comment: So yes I need more help I have tried saving the image in different ways(example: ico, jpeg, png, tiff and bmp) and still doesn't work!!

Comment: yes I have and still doesn't work for me

Comment: @user128854 Ok, I'm trying to work with very little information here.  Could you further explain what happens when you open the file browser?  Is it blank, are you in the wrong directory?  What folder did you download that image to?

Comment: I have downloaded the image to various files just to make sure and when I open them thow scratch it shows a blank screen with nothing on there(sorry for giving so little info I don't use this app very often nor have problems)

Comment: @user128854 Can you click on the home tab in the scratch file browser.  The one that I've highlighted in a rectangle in one of my pictures.  Describe to me what you see there.

Comment: I can see the following folders: Desktop, Documents, Downloads, music, Music, pictures, Python_games, Scratch, Templates and Videos

Comment: @user128854 Ok, do you have any idea where you downloaded those pictures?  What folder?

Comment: I download the picture to "Pictures" but when I try to find it  through scratch it doesn't appear

Comment: @user128854 So, that folder you found in the home folder "Pictures" tell me what's in there.

Comment: There is a picture called cat that I took by accident and still don't know how I took its a script.

Comment: @user128854 Ok, let's try something here.  Go to the command line and type the following commands.  `cd ~` and `wget https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg`.  Go back into scratch and click on the home tab again when selecting the background.  You should see a picture of a cat in there.

Comment: It says error 404: not found(I typed in cd~wget https://(...).jpg and tried without the cd~ and then without cd~, etc. But I typed in wget https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGgt98/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: Never mind I got it to work

Comment: @user128854 You found it in the home folder?

Comment: Yes.(so I can send you this message I'm just making space)

Comment: So how do I get the picture that I want?? And it did work I can put the cat!

Comment: @user128854 Well, I suppose you just aren't saving the pictures correctly.  Make sure you know what folder you are saving it to.  Learn the basic filesystem so you know where everything is.

Comment: @user128854 Maybe you can explain to me how you are saving your pictures?

Comment: I know how to find them and save them I just can't get the picture to appear in the scratch

Comment: I search the picture on the internet and left click on the select save as...  save them on to the Pi on the folder that I choose(pictures) and press save

Comment: @user128854 Very weird.  Can you try to save them to the home folder?  I'm guessing the pictures folder is in a different place than what you may think.

Comment: I have just tried again and didn't work maybe my raspberry Pi has some other problem that I don't see

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: @user128854 I'm sorry then, I honestly can't figure out what's going on... Good luck.

Comment: Thank you anyway for going so far and spending so much time with me thank you a lot!!!!

Comment: @user128854 Anytime, I'm sure you'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: And I have, just saving it the wrong way

Comment: @user128854 Congratulations, glad I could help.

Comment: You are a massive help I am surprised you helped me so far!!!!!! THANKSSSSS!!!!!!!!

Comment: I have!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I'll keep trying today and see if tomorrow it works!!!!!!